# How to add item to the beginning of List<T>?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, generic-list

I want to add a "Select One" option to a drop down list bound to a `List<T>`.

Once I query for the `List<T>`, how do I add my initial `Item`, not part of the data source, as the FIRST element in that `List<T>` ?  I have:

```
// populate ti from data               
List<MyTypeItem> ti = MyTypeItem.GetTypeItems();    
//create initial entry    
MyTypeItem initialItem = new MyTypeItem();    
initialItem.TypeItem = "Select One";    
initialItem.TypeItemID = 0;
ti.Add(initialItem)  <!-- want this at the TOP!    
// then     
DropDownList1.DataSource = ti;
```

Answer (score 915, accepted):

Use the [Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx) method:

```
ti.Insert(0, initialItem);
```

Comment: Would it be possible to insert at the end of the list?

Comment: @GaryHenshall yes, use the `Add` method, it inserts at the end.

Comment: Since .NET 4.7.1, you can use `Append()` and `Prepend()`. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59643605/1248177)

Comment: Doesn't work for me -- 
cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<initialItem>

Comment: Wouldnt this replace an existing value that is already in the list?

Comment: No this does not replace the first item

Answer (score 44):

Since .NET 4.7.1, you can use the side-effect free [`Prepend()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.prepend?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.7) and [`Append()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append?view=netframework-4.8). The output is going to be an IEnumerable.

```
// Creating an array of numbers
var ti = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

// Prepend and Append any value of the same type
var results = ti.Prepend(0).Append(4);

// output is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results));
```

---

Edit:

If you want to explicitly mutate your given list:

```
// Creating an array of numbers
var ti = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

// mutating ti
ti = ti.Prepend(0).ToList();
```

but at that point just use [`Insert(0, 0)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Depends on the use-case. Prepend() does something else, much better in some situations but will be unacceptable in others.

Comment: @HH `Prepend()` adds a value to the beginning of the sequence. Note that the original sequence is not altered. The result is a whole new sequence. The [Prepend's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.prepend?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.7) shows a lot of useful example.

Comment: Yes, but a "a whole new sequence" is not what was asked.

Comment: @HH Well you cant still mutate the list by re-assign it, but at the point you might as well use Insert...

Answer (score 26):

Update: a better idea, set the "AppendDataBoundItems" property to true, then declare the "Choose item" declaratively. The databinding operation will add to the statically declared item.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Please choose..."></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems.aspx

-Oisin

Answer (score 8):

Use **Insert** method of `List<T>`:

> List.Insert Method (Int32, T): `Inserts` an element into the List at the `specified index`.

```
var names = new List<string> { "John", "Anna", "Monica" };
names.Insert(0, "Micheal"); // Insert to the first element
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `List<T>.Insert`

While not relevant to your specific example, if performance is important also consider using `LinkedList<T>` because inserting an item to the start of a `List<T>` requires all items to be moved over. See [When should I use a List vs a LinkedList](https://stackoverflow.com/q/169973/5170571).