# How to insert element in first position in list which is in another list(C#)?

Tags: c#, list, insert, element

I have the following list:

```
var menuList = new List<MenuItem>;
```

The first element of this List is:

```
menuList.Add(new List<MenuItem>)
```

I want to add an element of type `MenuItem` at the first position of the List which is in the another List.

Comment: So the question is how to merge two `List<MenuItem>`s keeping second `List` first ?

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear as a description - could you give a [mcve] which shows what you mean? (In particular, one element of a `List<MenuItem>` can't be another `List<MenuItem>` - it has to be a `MenuItem`.)

Comment: No . I simply want to add an element at first position to a list which is in another list. Like list.Insert(0 , MenuItem) but if you want to do this in list in list .NET doesn't give me this option.

Comment: You can see at answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745994/how-can-i-add-to-a-lists-first-position

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add item to the beginning of List<T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390491/how-to-add-item-to-the-beginning-of-listt)

Answer (score 1):

Reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx

```
public void Insert(
    int index,
    T item
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you are not permitted to Add/insert `List<MenuItem>` To `menuList` since it is defined as `List<MenuItem>` so that which will accept only `MenuItem` to form the required list. Don't worry you can achieve this by using `List<List<MenuItem>>` so that you can add/insert `List<MenuItem>`s to the  `SuperMenu`

```
List<MenuItem> menuList = new List<MenuItem>();
menuList.Add(new MenuItem() { Name = "a",..  });
menuList.Insert(0, new MenuItem() { Name = "B",.. });
List<List<MenuItem>> SuperMenu = new List<List<MenuItem>>();
SuperMenu.Add(menuList);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code for a list of lists...in other words a list having its items as lists

```
List<List<MenuItem>> menuItems = new List<List<MenuItem>>();
for (int i = 0 ; i < menuItems.Count();  i++)
{
   MenuItem itemToInsert; // "something";
   List<MenuItem> innerList = menuItems[1];//Returns inner list at index i
   innerList.Insert(0, itemToInsert);// Now insert anywhere you want
}
```