# List<T> or LinkedList<T>

Tags: .net, algorithm, data-structures, collections

I need a data structure that holds a list of elements of the same type. Needed features are

- Add
- GetEnumerator
- (may be) Clear

An indexed access, sorting, searching, removing of elements are *not required*. What is the best collection class for it? The following aspects should be taken in consideration: performance, memory usage, behavior of the garbage collector.

My current candidates are `List<T>` and `LinkedList<T>`

Comment: Your answer must be here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169973/when-should-i-use-a-list-vs-a-linkedlist

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer
default to using `List<T>` in almost all cases.

Slightly longer answer
`LinkedList<T>` is only going to be better if you are doing a lot of adding and removing values in comparison to enumerating over those values and the size of the list is large. This should only be a factor in your choice if, subsequent to profiling you find using `List<T>` is a problem.

Longer answer

Assumption, you have identified the usage of one or the other as being a problem for performance.

It you do a lot of random access then `List<T>` will almost always be vastly faster no matter what.
If you enumerate a lot and rarely insert (or almost always insert near/at the end) the `List<T>` will almost always be faster.
If you are constantly inserting/removing in random locations but while iterating over the list so are already at or near the relevant node and will have at least several thousand elements you may want to try `LinkedList<T>`

Working out what values/usage translate to better performance are very much dependent on your usage profile. Microbenchmarks can be very misleading here since they brush under the carpet aspects of the linked lists behaviour like the nodes in in being distributed about in memory rather than nicely adjacent if they happen to get allocated all at once in your tests. Likewise pre-creating the `List<T>` with the right size can make a big difference.

As to computer science style reasoning and big O notation (which *really* need big N's to be meaningful in this case)

- operation

  - cost `List<T>`
  - cost `LinkedList<T>`
- insert at end

  - O(1) (amortized cost, allocation to double size as needed)
  - O(1) allocation each time
- insert at start

  - O(N) (though done as fast memory move so somewhat complex running time behaviour)
  - O(1)
- insert in location x (and remove as well)

  - O(N-x) (see comment for insert at end)
  - O(1)
- forward enumeration

  - O(N) (though cache misses minimized)
  - O(N) (though heavily dependent on cache locality)
- reverse enumeration

  - O(N)
  - O(N) (the `LinkedList<T>` implementation is doubly linked)
- random access

  - O(1)
  - O(N)

Memory usage is complex since List can have at most Count - 1 excess cells at any point but `LinkedList<T>` will consume a `LinkedListNode<T>` for each cell which is an additional 3 references (4/8 bytes a pop) plus the usual object overhead. In normal usage the List is likely to win but again this should only be something you worry about if you find the memory consumption is actually a problem.

Comment: Also you could add `Clear`. Both are O(n).

Answer (score 23):

Unless you are dealing with a massive structure or you plan on iterating over this thing a trillion times, it doesn't matter. Just pick one and **start coding**. If your app slows to a crawl later, figure out why then and change as necessary.

(Seriously, it does. not. matter. In the slightest. Every minute you spend on finding the answer to this question is a minute closer you could've been to having working code).

If anyone has gotten to the point where they *need* to know the difference, LinkedList is faster than List and could be used if you only need non-random, forward-only reading and appending functionality.

Comment: +1: Yes, don't sweat the small stuff unless it matters.  The nearly identical interfaces should make subsequent replacement trivial.  If it isn't, then you know you already picked the right datastructure b/c you're using its unique features.  OP should learn the differences for future reference, tho

Comment: Man, -1 for explaining how to be a better developer? Harsh :)

Comment: +1 for explaining how to be a better developer, as Albert said, stop reading and do.

Comment: +1 Sometimes the correct answer is not the one you were looking for.

Comment: While the answer is likely valid it would be a more useful answer if it also then stated what the differences are. perhaps someone will stumble upon this question because they are infact getting awful performance using a List and the particulars of their algorithm mean LinkedList is appropriate...

Comment: as of now http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+list+linkedlist this is the third hit

Comment: This answer reminds me one of the developers on my team. I work at a high-frequency trading firm and he's firmly in the "only profile when you actually have a performance problem" camp. Problem is, every time he adds something new, we have a new performance problem, because he doesn't concern himself with questions like this until after the fact (as you have essentially recommended). I'm not saying it's not good advice in general, but I really think it's premature to say things like "it doesn't matter" without understanding the context. Sometimes performance is a very important issue.

Comment: @Dan that's what a staging environment is for.

Answer (score 7):

I would use `List<T>` because all of your data will be stored sequentially if they're value types and still do well with reference types (internally, `List<T>` manages an array that it grows by a factor of two each time you run out of space).

`LinkedList<T>` used to make a lot more sense when things weren't IO bound. People will often quote its seeming "O(1)" nature. However, this discounts the true cost that comes with increased chances of page faults getting the nodes.

If you can get contiguous memory regions with an array or `List<T>` and avoid the potential of a page fault, you're much better off with modern processor and main memory caching lines.

If you know how many elements in advance you'll have, use an array. If you have a good idea of how many elements, use a `List<T>` (and in the constructor pass the likely upper bound to potentially avoid a reallocation).

The only time I'd use a `LinkedList<T>` is if you need to bump items in a list by one value constantly. For example, if you're implementing a [least recently used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Least_Recently_Used) cache algorithm and need to add something to the front and take something off the end.

For small items, it really won't make a difference. The generational garbage collector will compact scattered heap items together over time so the linked list won't get too bad.

I'd pick a `List<T>` and run with it unless you noticed problems (via profiling)

Comment: I'd avoid arrays in C#, they have terrible type safety - setting .Capacity beforehand is just as good, perf-wise.

Answer (score 7):

Unless you're dealing with hundreds of thousands or millions of entries, and you've profiled your program to see that there's a major problem, you probably won't notice the difference between the two.

Other than that:

> `LinkedList<T>` provides separate nodes of type `LinkedListNode<T>`, so insertion and removal are O(1) operations.

from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

If indexed access is not required, you're probably better off with a `LinkedList<T>`.  There's not much difference, but the LinkedList can be faster for the appends.

Comment: Actually, not the case (unless you care about symptomatic performance - "Worst Case" - for large data sets), the heap alloc, linking is much worse than the List's assign to inner array. *Prepends*, maybe, but again, only for medium-to-large data sets.

Comment: Like Simon says the _amortized_ cost will be much better for the List<T>. if you want *stable* append cost the linked list will be better though but that's very particular.

Answer (score 2):

Given your requirements for the interface, you should be using `ICollection<T>` everywhere in your code instead of referring to a particular concrete class.

The reason is that if you use `List` then you may write a bunch of code that uses `l[0]` to get the first item. On the other hand, if you use `LinkedList` then you might spread calls to `AddLast` throughout your code. To preserve the choice to switch, you need to avoid becoming accidentally dependent on features you don't really need. You need to use an interface that both containers can support.

So write a class like this:

```
public static class Collections
{
    public static ICollection<T> Make<T>()
    {
        return new List<T>();
    }
}
```

Then whenever you need a collection, do this:

```
ICollection<int> c = Collections.Make<int>();
```

Isolate your choice of container from the rest of your program. Now when you profile and change your mind, you just have to edit the `Make<T>` method.

Comment: No, he needs Add and possibly Clear.

Comment: I don't agree; unless you are writing a library or have strong architectural reasons in a large system. Pick one and use it like what it is. If you need to change it, change it and let the compiler tell you what needs fixing. Premature Abstraction is almost as bad as Premature Optimization.

Comment: Premature Abstraction is bad because of the cost. Picking the simplest data type for a variable costs nothing.

Comment: Earwicker (on simplest data type): I agree with you there. But IEnumerable is not a data type but a least-common-denominator interface. I don't think it's quite the same. I want to expand on this, so I posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613652 to elicit some healthy discussion around it.

Answer (score 0):

A LinkedList will carry more memory overhead (for the nodes), but is better if you are inserting many elements into the middle. A linked list will require more memory allocations too, as LinkedListNode is a class and is allocated dynamically. If you are not inserting elements (just appending), I would use a List. A list should be as fast or faster for appending, although it will occasionally have to enlarge.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is going to be large enough to matter, you need to roll your own ... otherwise just use a List.