# Why is a LinkedList Generally Slower than a List?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, list, linked-list

I started using some LinkedList’s instead of Lists in some of my C# algorithms hoping to speed them up. However, I noticed that they just felt slower. Like any good developer, I figured that I should do due diligence and verify my feelings. So I decided to benchmark some simple loops.

I thought that populating the collections with some random integers should be sufficient. I ran this code in Debug mode to avoid any compiler optimizations. Here is the code that I used:

```
var rand = new Random(Environment.TickCount);
var ll = new LinkedList<int>();
var list = new List<int>();
int count = 20000000;

BenchmarkTimer.Start("Linked List Insert");
for (int x = 0; x < count; ++x)
  ll.AddFirst(rand.Next(int.MaxValue));
BenchmarkTimer.StopAndOutput();

BenchmarkTimer.Start("List Insert");
for (int x = 0; x < count; ++x)
  list.Add(rand.Next(int.MaxValue));
BenchmarkTimer.StopAndOutput();

int y = 0;
BenchmarkTimer.Start("Linked List Iterate");
foreach (var i in ll)
  ++y; //some atomic operation;
BenchmarkTimer.StopAndOutput();

int z = 0;
BenchmarkTimer.Start("List Iterate");
foreach (var i in list)
  ++z; //some atomic operation;
BenchmarkTimer.StopAndOutput();
```

Here is output:

```
Linked List Insert: 8959.808 ms
List Insert: 845.856 ms
Linked List Iterate: 203.632 ms
List Iterate: 125.312 ms
```

This result baffled me. A Linked List insert should be O(1) whereas as List Insert is Θ(1), O(n) (because of copy) if it needs to be resized. Both list iterations should be O(1) because of the enumerator. I looked at the disassembled output and it doesn’t shed much light on the situation.

Anyone else have any thoughts on why this is? Did I miss something glaringly obvious?

Note: here is the source for the simple BenchmarkTimer class: http://procbits.com/2010/08/25/benchmarking-c-apps-algorithms/

Comment: Doesn't a Linked List allocate memory and create a new object for every insert (LinkedListNode), whereas List Insert doesn't allocate memory except for the copy for resized array?  That side-effect may have a bigger effect on the time than the algorithm's Big-O value.

Comment: That may be true, but why is the iteration even slower?

Comment: Following memory address links is maybe slower than sequentially reading through a block of array memory?  The only performance optimization I would use a LinkedList for is lots of deletions and insertions into the middle of my list because there is an obvious big-O difference for these scenarios.  Otherwise, there is no reason to include the overhead of memory allocation and link dereferencing.

Comment: Careful! You seem to be confused by Big-O-notation. It doesn't tell you how fast an algorithm/implementation is, it tells you how well it *scales*.

Comment: BTW, adding to the end, `List<>` needs to resize only `O(log2(n))` with `n` being the size of the final list (in your case ~24 times) because it doubles its capacity every time. And anyway 0xA3 is completely right.

Comment: @0xA3 - +1, an key bit of information that a lot of CS grads (that I've worked/gone to school with) don't seem to realize.

Comment: 0xA3:I must have misstated my analysis with big-O? I'd thought that by giving an example that contained 20 million iterations that would demonstrate a problem of scale.

Comment: You seem to "Add" at the end in case of `List<T>` and "Insert" at the start in case of `LinkedList<T>`. They both are different operations as far as performance is concerned. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5881045/661933) for a similar question which shows the advantage of using `LinkedList<T>`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Update** (in response to your comment): you're right, discussing big-O notation by itself is not exactly useful. I included a link to James's answer in my original response because he already offered a good explanation of the technical reasons why `List<T>` outperforms `LinkedList<T>` in general.

Basically, it's a matter of memory allocation and locality. When all of your collection's elements are stored in an array internally (as is the case with `List<T>`), it's all in one contiguous block of memory which can be accessed *very quickly*. This applies both to *adding* (as this simply writes to a location within the already-allocated array) as well as *iterating* (as this accesses many memory locations that are very close together rather than having to follow pointers to completely disconnected memory locations).

A `LinkedList<T>` is a *specialized* collection, which only outshines `List<T>` in the case where you are performing random insertions or removals from the *middle* of the list—and even then, only *maybe*.

As for the question of scaling: you're right, if big-O notation is all about how well an operation *scales*, then an O(1) operation should eventually beat out an O(>1) operation given a large enough input—which is obviously what you were going for with 20 million iterations.

This is why I mentioned that `List<T>.Add` has an **[amortized complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized) of O(1)**. That means adding to a list is *also* an operation that scales linearly with the size of the input, the same (effectively) as with a linked list. Forget about the fact that occasionally the list has to resize itself (this is where the "amortized" comes in; I encourage you to visit that Wikipedia article if you haven't already). They *scale* the **same**.

Now, interestingly, and perhaps counter-intuitively, this means that if anything, the performance difference between `List<T>` and `LinkedList<T>` (again, when it comes to *adding*) actually becomes **more obvious** as the number of elements increases. The reason is that when the list runs out of space in its internal array, it *doubles* the size of the array; and thus with more and more elements, the frequency of resizing operations *decreases*—to the point where the array is basically never resizing.

So let's say a `List<T>` starts with an internal array large enough to hold 4 elements (I believe that's accurate, though I don't remember for sure). Then as you add up to 20 million elements, it resizes itself a total of ~(log<sub>2</sub>(20000000) - 1) or **23 times**. Compare this to the **20 million times** you're performing the *considerably* less efficient `AddLast` on a `LinkedList<T>`, which allocates a new `LinkedListNode<T>` with every call, and those 23 resizes suddenly seem pretty insignificant.

I hope this helps! If I haven't been clear on any points, let me know and I will do my best to clarify and/or correct myself.

---

[James](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983059/why-is-a-linkedlist-generally-slower-than-a-list/5983124#5983124) is right on.

Remember that big-O notation is meant to give you an idea of how the performance of an algorithm *scales*. It does not mean that something that performs in guaranteed O(1) time will outperform something else that performs in amortized O(1) time (as is the case with `List<T>`).

Suppose you have a choice of two jobs, one of which requires a commute 5 miles down a road that occasionally suffers from traffic jams. Ordinarily this drive should take you about 10 minutes, but on a bad day it could be more like 30 minutes. The other job is 60 miles away but the highway is always clear and never has any traffic jams. This drive *always* takes you an hour.

That's basically the situation with `List<T>` and `LinkedList<T>` for purposes of adding to the end of the list.

Comment: I must have misstated my analysis with big-O? I'd thought that by giving an example that contained 20 million iterations that would demonstrate a problem of scale. However, I don't think that answers need to degenerate solely into explanations on big-O as much as they'd be appreciated by the would be internet searchers.

Comment: @JP: The short answer to your confusion is that adding to a `List<T>` is **also** O(1) when averaged out over real-world use (this is what *amortized* means). It is simply that the pseudo-constant performance for a `List<T>` is much faster than for a `LinkedList<T>`. So you're not seeing a difference in scalability because the two collections scale the same (for adding). Read my updated answer for a more in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 14):

Keep in mind that you've got lists of primitives.  For List this is very simple because it creates a whole array of int and it's very easy for it to shift these down when it doesn't have to allocate more memory.

Contrast this to a LinkedList that always must allocate memory to wrap the ints.  Thus I think the memory allocation is probably what's contributing the most to your time.  If you already had the node allocated, it should be faster overall.  I'd try an experiment with the overload of AddFirst that takes a LinkedListNode to verify (that is, create the LinkedListNode outside of the scope of the timer, just time the add of it).

Iterating is similar, it's much more efficient to go to the next index in an internal array than to follow links.

Comment: I'd add that adjacent allocated memory (as in `List<T>`) exploits memory caching much more than random allocated memory. Then less cache miss and therefore faster access time.

Answer (score 6):

I highly recommend the article *[Number crunching: why you should never use a linked-list again](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/340797/Number-crunching-Why-you-should-never-ever-EVER-us)*. There isn't much there that isn't anywhere else, but I spent quite a bit of time trying to figure out why **LinkedList<T>** was so much slower than **List<T>** in situations I thought would obviously favor the linked list before I found it, and after looking it over, things made a bit more sense:

> The linked list has items in **disjoint areas of memory**, and as a result, one could say it is **cache line hostile**, because it maximizes cache misses. The disjoint memory makes traversing the list result in frequent and costly unexpected RAM lookups.
>
> A vector [equivalent to **ArrayList** or **List<T>**] on other hand has its items stored in **adjacent memory**, and in so doing, is able to maximize cache utilization and avoid cache misses. Often, in practice, this more than offsets the cost incurred when shuffling data around.

If you'd like to hear that from a more authoritative source, this is from [Tips for Improving Time-Critical Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eye126ky.aspx#_core_cache_hits_and_page_faults) on MSDN:

> Sometimes a data structure that *looks* great turns out to be horrible because of poor **locality of reference**. Here are two examples:
>
> - **Dynamically allocated linked lists** (**LinkedListNode<T>** is a reference type, so it is dynamically allocated) can reduce program performance because when you search for an item or when you traverse a list to the end, each skipped link could miss the cache or cause a page fault. **A list implementation based on simple arrays might actually be much faster because of better caching and fewer page faults**— even allowing for the fact that the array would be harder to grow, it still might be faster.
> - Hash tables that use dynamically allocated linked lists can degrade performance. By extension, hash tables that use dynamically allocated linked lists to store their contents might perform substantially worse. **In fact, in the final analysis, a simple linear search through an array might actually be faster** (depending on the circumstances). Array-based hash tables *(IIRC, **Dictionary<TKey,TValue>** is array-based)* are an often-overlooked implementation which frequently has superior performance.

---

*This is my original (far less useful) answer where I did some performance tests.*

The general consensus seems to be that the linked list is allocating memory on every add (because the node is a class) and that does seem to be the case. I tried to isolate the allocation code from the timed code that adds items to the list and made a gist from the result: https://gist.github.com/zeldafreak/d11ae7781f5d43206f65

I run the test code 5 times and call `GC.Collect()` between them. Inserting 20 million nodes into the linked list takes 193-211ms (198ms) compared to 77-89ms (81ms), so even without the allocation, a standard list is a little over 2x faster. Iterating over a list takes 54-59ms, compared to 76-101ms for the linked list, which is a more modest 50%-ish faster.

Answer (score 5):

As James stated in his answer, memory allocation is probably one cause why the LinkedList is slower.

Additionally I believe the major difference originates from an invalid test. You are adding items to the beginning of the linked list, but to the end of the ordinary list. Wouldn't adding items to the beginning of the ordinary list shift the benchmarking results in favor of the *LinkedList* again?

Comment: Yes. Because then every add to the List would be O(n).  That's an even less fair comparison.  If a LinkedList has both a Head and Tail element, then adding to the front or the end is effectively the same thing and irrelevant.  Unless of course the actual usage requires inserting items into the front of the list.

Comment: @mellamokb: Just saying that's a usecase where a _LinkedList_ would be faster. A _LinkedList_ is meant to optimize such operations, of course causing some additional overhead which is noticed in his benchmarks by doing a unfair comparison. Unless the comparison is meant to show that a _LinkedList_ adds elements slower to the back of the list than a _List_, which is to be expected.

Comment: That is an excellent point @Steven, adding to the end or beginning of a LinkedList is O(1), and adding to the end of a List is O(1) - excluding resizes - but O(n) for beginning.

Comment: Only yours and Rick's answer address it.

Answer (score 3):

I've done the same test with `List` and `LinkedList` inserting actual objects (Annonymous Types, actually) into the list,and Linked List is slower than List in that case as well.

However, LinkedList DOES speed up if you insert items like this, instead of using AddFirst, and AddLast:

```
LinkedList<T> list = new LinkedList<T>();
LinkedListNode<T> last = null;
foreach(var x in aLotOfStuff)
{
    if(last == null)
        last = list.AddFirst(x);
    else
        last = list.AddAfter(last, x);
}
```

AddAfter seems to be faster than AddLast. I would assume internally .NET would track the 'tail'/last object by ref, and go right to it when doing an AddLast(), but perhaps AddLast() causes it to traverse the entire list to the end?

Answer (score 3):

Since the other answers didn't mention this, I'm adding another.

Although your print statement says `"List Insert"` you actually called `List<T>.Add`, which is the one kind of "insertion" that `List` is actually good at.  Add is a special case of just using the next element is the underlying storage array and nothing has to get moved out of the way.  Try really using `List<T>.Insert` instead to make it the worst case instead of the best case.

**Edit:**

To summarize, for the purposes of insertion, a list is a special-purpose data structure that is only fast at one kind of insertion: append to the end.  A linked-list is a general-purpose data structure that is equally fast at inserting anywhere into the list.  And there is one more detail: the linked-list has higher memory and CPU overhead so its fixed costs are higher.

So your benchmark compares general-purpose linked-list insertion against special-purpose list append to the end and so it is not surprising that the finely-tuned optimized data structure that is being used exactly as it was intended is performing well.  If you want linked list to compare favorably, you need a benchmark that list will find challenging and that means you will need to insert at the beginning or into the middle of the list.

Comment: Fair point. The language that I should have used in both cases was "Add" since I'm also calling an "AddFirst" on the Linked List.

Comment: @JP: No problem, I'm not quibbling about the word.  I'm saying that List.Insert(0, item) is the same as LinkedList.AddFirst.  Try running **that** and you will be shocked.

Comment: Rick: I would have figured that there wouldn't be a difference in performance between AddFirst or AddLast because I'd guess that the .NET implementation would keep a pointer to the head and the tail. Thoughts? Point being, what if I'd had used AddLast and Add for comparison...?

Comment: @JP: Yes, LinkedList doesn't care where you insert.  The moral of your story is if you are always adding at the end, then List wins hands down, no questions asked, end of story.  LinkedList can only ever hope to be faster if you are inserting at the beginning or in the middle.