# Why are changes to object reference preserved by original object?

Tags: java

When adding a node to the end of a linked list, the process below is used to find the last node and append a new node after it:

> The new node is always added after the last node of the given Linked List. For example if the given Linked List is 5->10->15->20->25 and we add an item 30 at the end, then the Linked List becomes 5->10->15->20->25->30.
>   Since a Linked List is typically represented by the head of it, we have to traverse the list till end and then change the next of last node to new node. (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-2-inserting-a-node/)

However, I am a bit confused as to how pointers actually work in this context. For example, when I do something like this:

```
int test = 4;
int pointer = test;
pointer += 1;
```

The value of test does not change, only the value of the pointer does. However, when adding a node to a linked list, a temporary pointer is used as follows:

```
Node last = head;  
while (last.next != null) {
    last = last.next; 
}    
last.next = new_node;
```

So essentially, at the very end, the `last` pointer is set equal to the last element of the linked list. Its `next` node is set equal to the new node being created. What I am confused about is how this impacts the original linked list. Wouldn't this simply set the next node of the pointer `last` rather than the actual next node of the last node of the linked list (in a similar manner as demonstrated with my `int test` above)?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] (with emphasis on **complete** and **minimal**). Two remarks: References != Pointers. --- Never omit `{` and `}`, even if possible, this is a very common and hard to find source of bugs

Comment: @Turing85 my apologies

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do linked list work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957976/how-do-linked-list-work)

Comment: @Progman my question is not specific to linked lists in any way, rather I am trying to understand how references work on a conceptual level

Comment: @Markoe7 Then check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: @Progman I did, maybe in the future try being helpful first and then voting to close a question after.

Comment: By suggesting a duplicate, Progman is trying to be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java does not have pointers.

It has "primitives" such as `int` which store values and "references" such as `Node` in your example that store a reference to an object.

So, in your first example you have two primitive variables, each stores a value and they are not connected in any way.
Assigning one to the other simply copies the value.

In your second example, `next` is a member of class `Node`.
`last` holds a reference to an object of class `Node`.
So, when you change the value of `last` it self, it simply points to another object.
But, when you change the value of a member of an object `last` points to, like this: `last.next = new_node` you change the **inside** of the object `last` points to.

This is why the change is preserved.