# In .net is linked list an underlying class for other Lists?

Tags: c#, .net

I was asked in a .net interview the significance of linkedlist in .net. I answered that linkedlist is used where you have to do a lot of inserts, but I have never had to use linkedlist in any of the code I wrote. The interviewer then told me that all the lists in .net use linkedlist as its underlying type. When I came home, I couldn't find anything online to support his statement. Can anyone comment on the validity of his statement?

Comment: The interviewer was wrong, could have been bait.

Comment: The interviewer is wrong - `List<T>` uses an array (`T[]`) as the underlying storage type.

Comment: This is a pretty good comparison as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169973/when-should-i-use-a-list-vs-a-linkedlist

Comment: This may be true in a very conceptual sense: when you're running on the metal  and you need to increase or delete elements arbitrarily, a linked list would be practical. However, when you're talking about .Net, a List is not a LinkedList.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your interviewer simply wrong. 
[LinkedList](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), by definiiton, is a list of entites connected with each other, so in order to get to some item `X`, you need traverse all the list, all along til that item. *There is no way you can access that item via index*(just an example). 
`LinkedList` is just a different datastructure, and for sure it wasn't used on all `BCL` list types.

It's very convenient choice when your going to have linked enitities and consume small memory (no additional data need other then pointer to neighbor), but you pay a cost of traversal/picking/removing/updating speed on it.

Comment: _"There is no way you can access that item via index"_ except by traversing the linked list from the first element to the next `n` times.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like BS to me. If you use reflection or check the [.net](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Net/Net/3@5@50727@3053/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/netfxsp/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Collections/Generic/List@cs/2/List@cs) / [mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs) source code you can see they use an array as base type:

```
private T[] _items;
```

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN says That the `c#` `List<T>` is like an `ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

> The List class is the generic equivalent of the ArrayList class. It
>   implements the IList generic interface using an array whose size is
>   dynamically increased as required.

This implies that the plain `List<T>` is **not** a linked list.

Comment: _equivalent of_ is not really _is an_

Comment: @HenkHolterman I don't know.  Something in me just can't comprehend the idea of a Linked list being called equivalent to something called `ArrayList`

Comment: Anyway, your answer only moves the problem to _"how is an ArrayList implemented"_