# What's the difference between a List and a LinkedList?

Tags: list

What is the difference ?

List list = new List();
LinkedList  Llist;

list.add(anyString); for example and Llist.AddFirst(anyString);

Comment: In the Java language?

Comment: Looks like C# to me. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169973/when-should-i-use-a-list-vs-a-linkedlist

Comment: Yes, please and i would like C# too

Answer (score 0):

In which language? In Java (and probably also the language you use) List is just an interface for various types of Lists. You can have single linked lists, double linked lists, circular lists etc.

Comment: Thank you Markus, i was thinking in Java and C#, i think that they are a lite bit similar

Answer (score 0):

**In Java:**

`List` is an interface, it does not provide a concrete implementation but only the definition of which operations are possible for classes implementing this interface. I.e. each implementation of `List` must provide a `size()` method returning the number of elements in the list.

`LinkedList` is a concrete implementation. It supports all the methods of `List` (probably some more, specific to its implementation). As the name suggests, it is implementing the interface using the [linked list approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).

A different `List` implementation would be `ArrayList`, which is internally using an array to implement the interface.

**In C#:**

In C# the naming is different. `List` is a concrete implementation of `IList`. Therefore `IList` is the interface, and `List` is the `ArrayList` implementation. There is also a `LinkedList` in C#.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to understand `Interface` and Implementation class in **Java**.
`List` is interface and `LinkedList` is concrete class implementing `List` interface.

`new` keyword and constructor symbol `()` is used to instantiate (create object) for concrete classes, but cannot be used for `Interface`

```
List list = new List();       //cannot compile as List is Interface
List list = new ArrayList();  //Valid and can compile
List list = new LinkedList(); //Valid and can compile
```

Before you go deep into `java.util.Collection` package, you should learn basic Java well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Java.in java there are many libraries that we can work from each has its own objects
so `List` belong to `java.awt` library while `LinkedList` belongs to `java.util`.

about `add` and `addFirst()`
I think the difference will be like this
    list.add(A)
    list.add(B)
    list.addFirst(C)
if you printed the list you will find the order is `C A B`
hope it helped